webrtc gives black screen only if you refresh the browser
I have a webrtc app used in this way:
Client(browser) initialize a call to a android webrtc app.

The android app gives video stream to the browser(one way trip).

Everything works just fine, except when the user refresh the page where the stream is, at that point the new connection will end up to a black screen.
So the initial call without the user doing a page refresh works ok.
And here are all the cases where it works fine:

Intial call without the user doing a refresh.
The user goes to another page and comes back where the video should start automatically - works fine.
I’ve set a timeout:

setTimeout(()=>{location.reload()}, 10000)
And the call init will happen just fine, there is a video stream..
But when the user click page refresh, the video is black - and this happens 100% of the time.
Any advice on what might the issue be? Or how to debug it on order to see exactly what and where the problem is?
Thanks.

I'm experiencing this exact same problem.  Are you using any UI framework, just as another data point?  Ours is running on React
